# Bootstrap 3 grid system. Nested rows and columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following:
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the right text, next to the drag and drop image.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="row row-no-padding">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <label for="image" class="control-label">Imagen de la Unidad</label>
            <div style="" class="dropzone admin-dropzone" id="imageDropzone"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <p>
            Tamaño recomendado: 135 x 135 px<br>
            Peso recomendado: menor a 100 kb<br>
            Formato recomendado: PNG
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried to use col offsets on the nested columns, but just move the column to the right and put it on a "next line".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your HTML code has wrong format for bootstrap row and col.
You should always put "..-col-.." class in the row class not in other "..-col-..".

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class=row>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <label for="image" class="control-label">Imagen de la Unidad</label>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row row-no-padding">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 form-group">          
            <div style="WIDTH:120PX;HEIGHT:120PX;BORDER: 1PX SOLID; background-color:black" class="dropzone admin-dropzone" id="imageDropzone"></div>              
        </div>        
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 form-group">          
            Tamaño recomendado: 135 x 135 px<br>
            Peso recomendado: menor a 100 kb<br>
            Formato recomendado: PNG
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
```